# jQuery loading external JavaScript: "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following piece of code to load JS files that require jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "timegrid/timegrid-api.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

However, the problem is that the JavaScript file relies on the Global $ variable instead of the local $ variable. The function($) returns a local variable $ that loads jQuery but I need the global $ to also be loaded. Using Chrome debugger, I see:

[image]

I also tried `window.load` but that gives the same result. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use jquery noConflict. You start by initially calling this before calling any other code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then when you want to do something with jQuery:

```
jQuery("div p").hide();
```

And when you want to use your initial library, use $ and however it works:

```
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```